# Someone who does not like excess

Tags: single-word-requests

I consider myself to be this type of person. A search did not yield anything, but I did find this website. What is the word you use to describe someone who does not like excess, in the sense of quantity of material possesions and / or in purchasing something more expensive because it has a couple of extra features that are not really needed?

Comment: Perhaps reasonable or rational.

Comment: Temperate or moderate seem to suit.

Comment: There's another website you might want to check out: wordhippo.com. If you need a synonym or antonym for a given word, go there and simply type the word in and ask for either one. You'll get, usually, a bunch of either. For example, given your question I might ask the wordhippo for an antonym for "materialistic." don

Comment: That would be a true "conservative".  However, they're scarcer than hens' teeth.

Comment: Do you mean not liking excess in a normal way, or not liking any bit of excess above the essentials for survival?

Comment: @Graffito That is too general.

Answer (score 22):

**prudent** - wise or judicious

**frugal** - requiring few resources

**discreet** - showing prudence and circumspection

**economical** - avoiding waste or extravagance

**practical** - suitable for a particular purpose

Comment: +1 for "frugal". That was the first word I thought of based on OP's description.

Comment: Could you add dictionary definitions for each of these?

Answer (score 21):

It sounds like being a [minimalist](http://www.theminimalists.com/minimalism/) to me, although some folks might confuse it with minimalism in art or music.

> What is minimalism? If we had to sum it up in a single sentence, we would say, Minimalism is a tool to rid yourself of life’s excess in favor of focusing on what’s important—so you can find happiness, fulfillment, and freedom.

The "Minimalist" disambiguation page on Wikipedia has an entry that points to [Simple Living](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_living) and explains that *'Simple living encompasses a number of different voluntary practices to simplify one's lifestyle. These may include reducing one's possessions, generally referred to as Minimalism...'*

There seems to be a lot of variation in what might specifically constitute a minimalist life style, but I think that context will make it less ambiguous.

Comment: I was leaning toward this too but there just isn't a definition that backs it up.

Comment: Yes, I don't think this sense of the word has made it into the dictionaries yet, and I think there is a lot of variation among what folks understand it to mean precisely, but I think I would understand the gist if someone told me "I'm a minimalist" in a particular context. If you search for 'minimalist lifestyle' usage seems pretty widespread. @ruby_newbie

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Rayner's suggestions, there are

- *parsimonious* (avoiding excess)
- *stingy* (ungenerous)
- *miserly* (inclined to hoard money)
- *Spartan* (characterized by self-denial)

*Stingy* and *miserly* are pejorative. *Spartan* might evince a degree of admiration.  *Parsimonious* is purely technical, a neutral evaluation.  A solution to a problem might be described as *parsimonious*, if it is the simplest possible answer.

There are many others.

Comment: Worth noting that stingy and miserly, at least, have negative connotations. As with all connotations, tone of voice can affect it, but in general, if you're calling someone stingy, you're saying they're too cheap, rather than simply frugal.

Comment: In British English, and in my experience, 'parsimonious' would generally be regarded as having a negative connotation; pretty much identical to 'miserly' or 'stingy' in that it would refer to carefulness in outlay of money rather than the nature of what the money bought.,

Comment: @Spagirl -- good to know.  Maybe it's because I am in a technical industry; whenever I hear "parsimonious", it's to describe something that uses no more resources than necessary.  On the other hand, we use "greedy" and "lazy" in purely descriptive, non-perjorative ways too.

Answer (score 14):

The term [ascetic](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#safe=off&hl=en&q=define:+ascetic) comes to mind:

> characterized by or suggesting the practice of severe self-discipline
>   and abstention from all forms of indulgence, typically for religious
>   reasons.
>
> - "an ascetic life of prayer, fasting, and manual labor"
> - synonyms:   austere, self-denying, abstinent, abstemious,
>     self-disciplined, self-abnegating; simple, puritanical, monastic;
>     reclusive, eremitic, hermitic; celibate, chaste
> - "an ascetic life"
>
> a person who practices severe self-discipline and abstention.
>
> - synonyms:   abstainer, puritan, recluse, hermit, anchorite, solitary;
>     fakir, Sufi, dervish, sadhu; archaiceremite
> - "a desert ascetic"

(I just saw this term in a comment on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322073/opposite-of-hoarder).)

Answer (score 4):

If you feel excess is a bit unethical, then **self disciplined**  would work.

If the issue is monetary, then **frugal** or **shrewd** would work.

If you find excess in bad taste, then **unostentatious** would work.

In general, you are a **sensible** person.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing the various connotations to narrow down to what the OP might need

Answer (score 3):

One could say that this person is *not materialistic*, or they may be *moderating*. You could find antonyms for materialistic/greedy. For example:

> I am not a very materialistic person.
>
> I am a moderating person.

You could also say something that states that it is easier for you to restrain yourself(*abstemious*). *Thrifty* might also be an acceptable term.

Comment: "Moderating"?  I have never heard it used this way.  As it has a lot of other meanings, I would avoid it.

Comment: I see, upon looking back, I see my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: All things in moderation.

Comment: @Rayner right, it's just the wrong word form; here it would just be a "moderate" person, rather than a "moderating" person, with the difference being nature versus action or role.

Answer (score 2):

I like the word *content* (or contented), meaning satisfied with what one has. Contented people are grateful for what they have; they are not acquisitive, envious, or discontented because they think they do not have enough stuff, or stuff that is the "latest and greatest."

Answer (score 2):

Abstemious

From the free dictionary

> adjective: moderate or sparing

Answer (score 1):

At the more extreme end you might call them an ascetic.

From the Free Dictionary... Noun: A person who renounces material comforts and leads a life of austere self-discipline, especially as an act of religious devotion.

Answer (score 1):

Unextravagant. That is, the opposite of [extravagant](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/extravagant):

> adjective
>
> 1. spending much more than is necessary or wise; wasteful:
>      *an extravagant shopper.*
> 2. excessively high:
>      *extravagant expenses; extravagant prices.*
> 3. exceeding the bounds of reason, as actions, demands, opinions, or passions.
> 4. going beyond what is deserved or justifiable:
>      *extravagant praise.*

Answer (score 0):

Another word you may consider is *sparing*. Here is the explanation given by the free dictionary:

> sparing adj.
>   1. Given to or marked by prudence and restraint in the use of material resources.
>   Synonyms: sparing, frugal, thrifty, economical

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ***temperate***, sense 2

From https://www.google.com/search?q=temperate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

```
tem·per·ate
ˈtemp(ə)rət/
adjective
adjective: temperate

    1.
    of, relating to, or denoting a region or climate characterized by mild temperatures.
    synonyms:   mild, clement, benign, gentle, balmy
    "temperate climates"
    antonyms:   extreme
    2.
    showing moderation or self-restraint.
    "Charles was temperate in his consumption of both food and drink"
    synonyms:   self-restrained, restrained, moderate, self-controlled, disciplined; More
```

Answer (score 0):

***penurious***

> :  given to or marked by extreme stinting frugality.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penurious)